# I can't run .bat and .cmd files with start command (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I can run .bat and .cmd files typing his names in windows console, but if I run with `start "" file.bat` I get this error: `System can't run specified program`.

I have tested with a very simple file `test.bat` with this content:

```
echo "hola"
```

And running:

```
start "" test.bat
```

Without success.

If I run just `test.bat` it works perfectly. Also work with `cmd /c test.bat` and `cmd /k test.bat`. Running .exe files with start command is also working good.

Many months ago I had installed ansicon (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) and have not problems.

Some days ago I had also installed consolez (https://github.com/cbucher/console/releases) and maybe I have broken something, but I don't know where start to find. I'm testing from cmd.exe command line, not from ConsoleZ.

I can't run a restore point because I have an SSD hard drive and disabled Restore Points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your COMSPEC variable is corrupted. On my Windows 7 machine I have `ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`. A corrupted COMSPEC value will also prevent pipes from working.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works good. I have looking and default value is: `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

To change your COMSPEC environment variable, you can put default value `(%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe)` with this file.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]  
"ComSpec"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,63,\
  00,6d,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00
```

**Note**: You need to reboot to apply new changes